# How to ensure NSOutlineView inside a custom view renders full height (without scrolling)

Tags: macos, cocoa, autolayout, nsoutlineview

I have a window with two custom views stacked on top of each other. I use auto layout constraints, as follows:

Top view leading, top, and trailing edges are tied to superview.
Bottom view leading, bottom, and trailing edges are tied to superview.
There is a fixed vertical space constraint between two views.
Bottom view has a fixed height constraint.
Top view has a it's compression resistance set to 751.

So far so good. The idea is that the bottom view height is fixed and as the window is resized, the top view height adjusts to compensate.

Both top and bottom views have other views/controllers loaded in, as appropriate. The bottom view ends up containing an outline view with a half-dozen entries. I would like that outline view not to scroll. In other words, I would like to automatically adjust my bottom view fixed height constraint to match the height of the outline view required for it not to scroll.

Ideally, I'd prefer to solve this with auto layout without having to write code. But, if that's stretching beyond what auto layout can do, code help would be appreciated as well.

Comment: Is the outlineView embedded in a scroll view?  I'd imagine it can't be, if you want the outlineview height to matter.

Comment: Hmm. Is it possible for the outline view to exist outside a scroll view? I can't figure out a way to make that happen in Interface Builder.